# JUnit Design in terms of patterns

Tags: design-patterns, junit

I'm evaluating JUnit in terms of its design.

JUnit imported has 2 important parts: the code for v3.x (backwards compatibility reasons) and the code for v4.x.

v3.x has a pretty clear design and I've identified multiple patterns and good OO practices (Template Method Pattern, Composite, Adapter, etc).

v4.x however proves to be a lot more difficult. After some analysis I've been unable to really find distinct patterns in it. I did find this citation however: "The evolution of JUnit 3 to JUnit 4 comes to mind. JUnit 3 was a small framework that used several patterns like Composite, Template Method and Command. JUnit 4 leverages the Annotations meta-programming facilities introduced in J2SE 5.0. The use of the patterns disappeared and the framework evolved into a small set of annotations plus a test runner infrastructure that executes the annotated Java code."

from http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1404056

So, I'm in a bit of a bind here. I'm unsure how to analyze v4.x. Is the bottom line that is has no clear design? That it is a mish mash of code? Or am I missing something and is there something of a design behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Patterns are the same in JUnit 4 as they were in Junit 3.  The difference is the inheritance restriction that all test classes must be subclasses of `TestCase` is no longer required.

I would still argue that JUnit 4 still uses template method it's just the name of the templated methods is not limited to a single name.  Now instead of using a template method `void setup()` which is called first before each test, the template is "call all methods, whatever they are named, that are annotated by the `@Before` annotation.  The general idea of the template pattern is still there.

Similarly the Command Pattern is still there: instead of invoking each `public void` parameterless method that starts with the word "test" as a Command, JUnit 4 instead invokes any `public void` parameterless method that has the `@Test` annotation.

Also, the 20 Gang of Four Patterns aren't the only Design Patterns around.  There are many Test Specific Patterns that were difficult or clumsy to do in Junit 3 that are now easy to do in JUnit 4.  For example Test Fixture Setup and Test Fixture Teardowns all had to be done manually in Junit 3 and often would lead to bugs where the fixtures weren't correctly reset between test classes.  Now Junit 4 has `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` (also template methods).

I would recommend reading *XUnit Test Patterns* by Gerard Meszaros.  It was written in the JUnit 3 days but is still applicable.

Comment: Thank you, I was getting confused due to the JUnit 4 structure.

Now that you explain it, it does indeed seem like some patterns survive in some way or another. However, I still find JUnit 3 to be more accessible. Would you agree that the overall design of JUnit 4 has degraded from JUnit 3?

Perhaps I arrive at that conclusion because I'm biased for the more traditional Patterns and by that quote above, but still I'm interested in additional opinions on the subject.

Comment: @Sven No, I do not think the overall design has degraded in JUnit 4. In fact, I think it has improved.  I'll give 2 examples:  1.  Because test methods are now annotated with `@Test` you no longer need to have the method names start with "test" which makes the method names shorter and more intent revealing.  2. Since test classes no longer require extending `TestCase` and Java requires single inheritance, your test classes may now extend other classes that have nothing to do with JUnit allowing your code to be better designed